# material ui grid alignItems flex-start only applies to first row when items are full width

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material ui grid, and I want to create a grid container with a specified height (e.g 200px) which has full width items. I want items to fill the container from top, and I want remainder space to be only in bottom of container.

What I want:
[image]

What I get:
[image]

My code:

```
<Grid
    container
    xs={12}
    justifyContent="center"
    alignItems="flex-start"
    css={css`
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    `}
>
    <Grid xs={12}>first row</Grid>
    <Grid xs={12}>second row</Grid>
    <Grid xs={12}>third row</Grid>
</Grid>
```

Can you please help me to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `AlignContent` instead of `AlignItems`, solved the problem.